# Why does sizeof(ar)/ sizeof(ar[0]) not work properly on a vector when passed to a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get to know c++ better and came across this confusion.

```
int simpleArraySum(const vector<int> ar) {
  int n=sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]);
  int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
      sum+=ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

When I passed a vector of 10 elements the result was lower than expected. I checked that n=6 unlike when I use size() which gives n=10. My confusion comes since the way the code is written works normally in main with sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0]).

Comment: That's why `std::vector` provides the `.size()` member function...

Comment: If your compiler is up to date and supports the current C++Standard, `std::size` is also useful.

Comment: _"My confusion comes since the way the code is written works normally in main with sizeof(ar)/sizeof(ar[0])."_ Please provide an example where this code works in main with a vector. I'm very interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the "sizeof trick" have *never* worked on a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

The size of a `std::vector` object is the size of the `std::vector` object itself, not the possible data handled by the vector.

If you want to get the number of elements from a `std::vector` object, use the [`size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) member function.

---

The "sizeof trick" only works on actual arrays, like e.g.

```
int array[10];
std::cout << sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) << '\n';  // Will print 10
```

---

As for the problem you try to solve with your function, there are much better ways to handle it.

- First you could iterate using the size (like you do now)

  ```
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ar.size(); ++i)
      sum += ar[i];
  ```
- Then you could iterate using iterators

  ```
  for (auto i = ar.begin(); i != ar.end(); ++i)
      sum += *i;
  ```
- Then you have [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

  ```
  for (auto value : ar)
      sum += value;
  ```
- Lastly you can use a [standard algorithm function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) like [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

  ```
  int simpleArraySum(std::vector<int> const& ar)
  {
      return std::accumulate(begin(ar), end(ar), 0);
  }
  ```

Comment: *not the possible data it contains* And how can this be? No, std::vector` is not the Kwisatz Haderach, but it dynamically allocates a buffer to contain it's data. `sizeof` a `vector` is the pointer to this buffer plus some book-keeping variables and perhaps a bit of padding.

Comment: @user4581301 [`sizeof()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_sizeof_operator.htm) "*is a compile time operator*", how can it account for size changes in a dynamic container?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does sizeof(ar)/ sizeof(ar[0]) not work properly on a vector ...

`sizeof(ar)/ sizeof(ar[0])` is an expression that gives you the length of an array, and only an array. `std::vector` is not an array. `std::vector` is a class (template).`sizeof(std::vector)` is entirely unrelated to the number of elements it has i.e. its length.

The size of all types is compile time constant. `std::vector`'s can contain a variable number of elements that is not compile time constant. Therefore the size of vector type cannot depend on the number of elements.

> ... when passed to a function?

It won't work when not passing into a function either.